# Cloudy.ec API authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, authentication, upload

I'm trying to use Cloudy.ec API:

```
http://www.cloudy.ec/api
```

Some actions with this API need authentication, but link to authenticate is not provided. I'm trying to pass my username and password when I'm uploading (I think it's only thing which need authentication) like that:

```
http://www.cloudy.ec/api/upload.php?user=MY_USERNAME&pass=MY_PASSWORD
```

I get output message about invalid session ID:

```
{"resultCode":"400","message":"Empty SessionID parameter","result":1,"data":null}
```

And my question is: how to get that SessionID parametr?

And one addition question: is there any gem to work with Cloudy.ec in Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Authentication link is:

```
http://www.cloudy.ec/api/auth.php?action=doLogin&username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx
```